# Using multiple windows in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am building a very base movie recommendation GUI in python and I am trying to have it open a new window when a genre is selected. I am able to open the window but I am having trouble assigning my radio buttons to a new class. I want to be able to select a genre, hit next and start with my recommendation based on the button the user selects.

```
from tkinter import *
class movie1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Movie Recommendation")

        self.label = Label(master, text= "Welcome to the movie recommendation application! \n Please select the genre of the movie you would like to see.")
        self.label.pack(padx=25, pady=25)

        CheckVar1 = StringVar()

        C1 = Radiobutton(master, text = "Action", variable = CheckVar1, value=1)
        C1.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)
        C2 = Radiobutton(master, text = "Comedy", variable = CheckVar1, value=2)
        C2.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)
        C3 = Radiobutton(master, text = "Documentary", variable = CheckVar1, value=3)
        C3.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)
        C4 = Radiobutton(master, text = "Horror", variable = CheckVar1, value=4)
        C4.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)
        C5 = Radiobutton(master, text = "Romance", variable = CheckVar1, value=5)
        C5.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.nextbutton = Button(master, text="Next", command=self.reco)
        self.nextbutton.pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=10, pady=10)

    def reco(self):
        self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = movie2(self.newWindow)

class movie2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)

    def C1(self):
        print("option 1")    


root = Tk()
my_gui = movie1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: *I want to be able to select a genre, hit next and start with my recommendation based on the button the user selects*--If you mean you want the 2nd class to know what was selected, just send it to movie2, so self.app=movie2(self.newWindow, genre_selected)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the selected value to the new class:

```
class movie1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.CheckVar1 = StringVar()
        ...

    def reco(self):
        ...
        choice = self.CheckVar1.get()
        self.app = movie2(self.newWindow, choice)

class movie2:
    def __init__(self, master, choice):
        ...
        print("you chose: %s" % choice)
        ...
```